# How can I see where runtime.futex is coming from? It only has "System" as parent

Tags: go, profiling

Running `go tool pprof` with a cpu profile for https://github.com/vimeo/statsdaemon and typing "*web*" I get an svg profile with extensive use of "*runtime.futex*". But I can't see where it's coming from, it just says "*System*".

I want to know which code my program invokes, that causes so much time spent in `runtime.futex`.

[image: profile screenshot]

To be sure I passed `'-nodefraction=0'` which makes it not drop nodes in the web svg view, though it says "*showing top 80 nodes out of 246 (cum >= 0.11s)*", maybe this is related.

I tried https://code.google.com/p/gperftools/ and it shows the same.
The viz drops no nodes or edges, but still "runtime.futex" just shows up under "*System*" and that's the root node?

Comment: are you using osx? https://godoc.org/rsc.io/pprof_mac_fix

Comment: No, Arch Linux 3.18 64bit

Answer (score 8):

A futex or "Fast user space mutex" is a linux system call that is used for basic locking. I imagine the go runtime uses it quite a bit under the hood.

Without seeing some of the code it's hard to say for sure but for highly concurrent code with a lot of coordination using channels it's possible that the futex calls really are coming from System and no particular function.

Answer (score 5):

When I've faced with such issue I've used `runtime/trace` where I've see that some function was called very often and this function creates new ticker by

```
ticker := time.NewTicker()
```

but does not stop it by

```
defer ticker.Stop()
```

Also, don't forget to stop timers as well:

```
timer := time.NewTimer(duration)
defer timer.Stop()
```

Comment: That was exactly my problem. Thank you